# Remove labels in countdown.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get countdown.js to return something like this:

Months:Days:Weeks:Hours:Seconds

so something like this with two digits each: 
11:02:12:06:12

So far I see the the countdown object has a constructor function which adds the hours and minutes labels, and I can't figure out how to remove them. Here is what I have so far:

```
var targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01);
var totalEnd = targetDate.setHours(targetDate.getHours() + 8);
var time = countdown( null, totalEnd, countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);
console.log(time);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Read the docs:](http://countdownjs.org/readme.html) "To explicitly exclude units like "not weeks and not milliseconds" combine bitwise-NOT and bitwise-AND: `~countdown.WEEKS & ~countdown.MILLISECONDS`"

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand, I saw this in the documentation but I assumed it was just excluding everything, not the labels. I can't get it to spit out anything that is different than the default. Even when changing that parameter in countdown. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused, the countdown library doesn't explicitly format the html, you can just use the vars returned on the timespan object and format them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The Countdown.js provides methods

```
 countdown.resetLabels();

 countdown.setLabels(singular, plural, last, delim, empty, formatter);
```

**The arguments:**

- singular is a pipe ('|') delimited ascending list of singular unit
  name overrides
- plural is a pipe ('|') delimited ascending list of plural unit name
  overrides
- last is a delimiter before the last unit (default: ' and ')
- delim is a delimiter to use between all other units (default: ', ')
- empty is a label to use when all units are zero (default: '')
- formatter is a function which takes a number and returns a string
  (default uses Number.toString()),

allowing customization of the way numbers are formatted, e.g., commas every 3 digits or some unique style that is specific to your locale.

**The following would be effectively the same as calling countdown.resetLabels():**

```
countdown.setLabels(
    ' millisecond| second| minute| hour| day| week| month| year| decade| century| millennium',
    ' milliseconds| seconds| minutes| hours| days| weeks| months| years| decades| centuries| millennia',
    ' and ',
    ', ',
    '',
    function(n){ return n.toString(); });
```

**Make changes to the above method as per your requirement like (replace "and" & "," with ":")**

```
countdown.setLabels(
        ' | | | | | | | | | | ',
        ' | | | | | | | | | | ',
        ':',
        ':',
        '',
        function(n){ return n.toString(); });
```

---

```
countdown(Start Date, End Date, countdown.YEARS | countdown.MONTHS | countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS , 5).toString();
```

Reference: http://countdownjs.org/readme.html (search for Localization)

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
var targetDate = new Date(2050, 00, 01);
var totalEnd = targetDate.setHours(targetDate.getHours() + 8);
var units = ~(countdown.MILLENNIA |
    countdown.CENTURIES |
    countdown.DECADES |
    countdown.YEARS |
    countdown.MINUTES |
    countdown.MILLISECONDS);

var time = countdown( null, totalEnd, units);
console.log(time);
```